# Как поправить расположение картинки в контейнере?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, qlayout

Я создал цветной контейнер `box`, в который помещаю надпись `label`, кнопку `btn` и изображение `picture`. К сожалению, `picture` я добавляю неправильно, из-за чего окно приложения выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас у меня есть три проблемы:

1. Я масштабировал изображение так, чтобы его размер был равен размеру
   контейнера, но оно все равно вышло за его пределы `box`. Мне нужно, чтобы между боковыми стенками контейнера и изображением не было расстояния.
2. Картинка не появляется
   полностью, на скрине можно видеть только ее маленькую часть. Я не понимаю, как это исправить.
3. Мне необходимо расположить изображение в `box` так, чтобы оно
   **полностью** прижалось к верхней части контейнера, при этом другие виджеты контейнера должны остаться на своих местах, не изменив свой размер.

Примерно так должен выглядеть контейнер `box` в итоге:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как поправить расположение картинки в контейнере?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        main_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        container.setStyleSheet('background: #2A303D;')
        container.setFixedWidth(250)
        container.setMinimumHeight(150)

        main_box.addWidget(container)
        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container)

        picture = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        picture.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('im.png'))
        picture.setFixedSize(250, 250)
        box.addWidget(picture)

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text')
        label.setStyleSheet('color: white;')
        box.addWidget(label, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        btn.setStyleSheet('color: white;')
        box.addWidget(btn, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**UPD:** Если использовать метод `setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)`, то при больших размерах окна между изображением и верхней границей контейнера появляется лишнее расстояние:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста, скажите, как от него избавиться?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        main_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        container.setStyleSheet('background: #2A303D;')
        container.setFixedWidth(250)
        container.setMinimumHeight(300)

        main_box.addWidget(container)
        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container)
        box.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        picture = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        picture.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('im.png').scaled(250, 250, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        box.addWidget(picture)

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text')
        label.setStyleSheet('color: white;')
        box.addWidget(label, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        btn.setStyleSheet('color: white;')
        box.addWidget(btn, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> QPixmap::scaled(int width, int height, Qt::AspectRatioMode aspectRatioMode = Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::TransformationMode transformMode = Qt::FastTransformation) const
>
> Возвращает копию растрового изображения, масштабированного до прямоугольника с заданной шириной
> и высотой в соответствии с заданными aspectRatioMode и transformMode.
> Если ширина или высота равна нулю или отрицательна, эта функция возвращает нулевое растровое изображение.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        main_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        main_box.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)                       # +++


        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        container.setStyleSheet('background: #2A303D;')
        container.setFixedWidth(250)
        container.setMinimumHeight(300)                               # ? 150

        main_box.addWidget(container)
        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container)

        picture = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        picture.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('im.png').scaled(250, 250))    # +++
#        picture.setFixedSize(250, 250)
        box.addWidget(picture)

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text')
        label.setStyleSheet('color: white;')
        box.addWidget(label, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        btn.setStyleSheet('color: white;')
        box.addWidget(btn, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> QBoxLayout::setStretch(int index, int stretch)
>
> Sets the stretch factor at position index. to stretch.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        main_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        container.setStyleSheet('background: #2A303D;')
        container.setFixedWidth(250)
        container.setMinimumHeight(300)                               

        main_box.addWidget(container)
        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container)
        box.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        picture = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        picture.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('zootopia.png').scaled(250, 250, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))        
        box.addWidget(picture)

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text')
        label.setStyleSheet('color: white;')
        box.addWidget(label, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        btn.setStyleSheet('color: white;')
        box.addWidget(btn, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        box.setStretch(0, 0)                                         # +++
        box.setStretch(1, 1)                                         # +++
        box.setStretch(2, 1)                                         # +++

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По умолчанию, масштабирование будет `Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio`, а это тоже самое что `setScaledContents(True)` у `QLabel`, т.е. картинка при масштабировании займет все указанное место, растянувшийсь. Это особенно заметно на прямоугольных вытянутых по ширине картинках :)

Comment: @S. Nick, спасибо! К сожалению, осталась одна очень важная деталь. Я уточнял об этом в вопросе. Мне нужно, чтобы между стенками контейнера и изображением не оставалось абсолютно никакого пространства, но методом `setContentsMargins()` я не могу воспользоваться, так как мне нужно оставить размеры и расположение других виджетов контейнера прежними. Я не знаю, что делать:(

Comment: @MAXIM045 уберите `main_box.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)` , добавьте `box.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: @MAXIM045  или `box.setContentsMargins(0, 20, 0, 0)` отрегулируйте как вам надо.

Comment: Знаю, что надоел. Я не могу придумать, как это гуглить, поэтому мучаю вас. Если использовать данный метод, между картинкой и верхней границей контейнера при большом размере окна остается лишнее расстояние. Если вам будет не трудно, пожалуйста, скажите как это исправить. Прошу прощения, что опять беспокою вас

Comment: @MAXIM045 добавьте в вопрос последний вариант вашего кода. Прикрепите ваше изображение. Как-то покажите что вы хотите получить, ну или что там у вас лишнее.

Comment: @S.Nick, я изменил вопрос :)

Comment: @MAXIM045 я добавил свой ответ. The End.

Answer (score 1):

Можно руками масштабировать картинку через [QPixmap::scaled](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#scaled-1) и если указывать [Qt.KeepAspectRatio](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#AspectRatioMode-enum) (сохранение пропорций), то должно получить как вы описали:

```
img = QtGui.QPixmap('im.png').scaled(250, 250, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
picture.setPixmap(img)
```

---

**Другой вариант**, если указать [setScaledContents(true)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#scaledContents-prop), тогда картинка займет все пространство `QLabel`:

```
picture.setScaledContents(True)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. К сожалению, не могу принять второй ответ :(

Comment: @MAXIM045, ок :): но обратите внимание на мой комментарий про `Qt.KeepAspectRatio` и `Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio`, мне кажется, вам нужен `Qt.KeepAspectRatio`

Comment: Да, я прочитал об этом, спасибо