# Как убрать фон виджета QLabel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Мой код наполняет цветной контейнер `box` тремя виджетами - `label1`, `label2` и `picture`.

`label1` и `label2` являются проcтыми надписями, а `picture` - изображение, которое я получаю с помощью класса `MyPicture`. Когда окно приложения становится слишком маленьким, `label1` и `label2` оказываются поверх `picture`. Мне необходимо оставить эту возможность, так контейнер становится компактнее при необходимости. **Т.е. задать минимальный размер контейнера больше, чем размер картинки я не могу.**

Сейчас надписи `label1` и `label2` обладают собственным цветным фоном:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно как-то избавиться от этого фона, чтобы надписи выглядели так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фон цветного контейнера должен остаться прежним, надписи должны продолжить менять свое местоположение, при изменении размера окна. **Под надписями `label1` и `label2` в контейнере будут находиться и другие виджеты, трогать которые мне бы не хотелось.**

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как убрать фон `label1` и `label2`?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia

class MyPicture(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, picture, x, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyPicture, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setFixedSize(x, x)

        self.setPicture(picture, x)

    def setPicture(self, picture, x):
        self.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(x, x, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        main_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        container.setStyleSheet('background: #2A303D;')
        container.setMinimumSize(250, 300)
        container.setMaximumWidth(300)                               

        main_box.addWidget(container)
        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container)
        box.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        picture = picture = MyPicture('im.png', 300)       
        box.addWidget(picture, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text number 1')
        label1.setStyleSheet(qss)
        box.addWidget(label1, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text number 2')
        label2.setStyleSheet(qss)
        box.addWidget(label2, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)


        box.setStretch(0, 0)
        box.setStretch(1, 2)
        box.setStretch(2, 2)

qss = '''QLabel {
         color: red;
         font: bold 16px;
         border: none;
         margin: 0px;
         padding: 0px;
      }'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Обидно, что в вопросе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1099838 вы приняли не мой ответ, а в итоге используйте наработки моего, а я между прочим раньше ответил :)

Comment: @gil9red, когда я пришел к своему компьютеру в тот день, на экране было уже два ответа, данные в одну минуту. Я не знал, что делать. Выбрал тот ответ, который был выше. Прошу прощения, что вынужден кого-то обижать. До сих пор очень удивлен, что нельзя выбрать несколько правильных ответов. Надеюсь, когда-нибудь это исправят.

Comment: @gil9red не обижайтесь пожалуйста, я вам компенсирую все.
Вы конечно понимаете, что я, публикуя ответ, не видел, что вы уже ответили.

Comment: Все ок :) кст, хочу похвалить ваши вопросы, оформление очень хорошее. И код есть, и примерная картинка как хотели бы сделать. За одно такое хорошее оформление вопросов можно поставить им плюс

Comment: @S.Nick, все нормально :) вы отлично оформляете ответы, бывают они получаются излишними, но видно что вы старались и за одно это можно отметить ответ плюсом :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменение стиля родительского виджета меняет стиль детей:

```
container.setStyleSheet('background: #2A303D;')
```

Поэтому, укажите детям другой задний фон:

```
qss = '''QLabel {
         color: red;
         font: bold 16px;
         background: transparent;
         border: none;
         margin: 0px;
         padding: 0px;
      }'''
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Это именно то, что я хотел